# Passing URL Params to new browser window/tab on USB drive from Flash moviclip

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, internet-explorer-10, usb-drive

I'm running a website from a USB drive and trying to pass parameters through the address bar to a new window when a button is clicked in the embedded flash swf.

The problem is that on some workstations the parameters are stripped from the URL. On others it works fine.

I have a movieclip button that when clicked calls this function:

```
function onReleaseHandler(myEvent:MouseEvent) {     
    var printURL = "html/certPopup.html";
    var request:URLRequest = new URLRequest(printURL);
    var variables:URLVariables = new URLVariables();
    variables.vModTitle = modTitle;
    variables.vFirstName = firstName;
    variables.vLastName = lastName;
    variables.vLang = language;
    request.data = variables;
    navigateToURL(request, "_self");
}
```

On machines where this is working, the certPopup.html page opens in a new tab and the URL in the address bar looks like this:

> file:///G:/courses/flash/1/EN/course/html/certPopup.html?vFirstName=Charlie&vModTitle=This%20is%20the%20Title&vLang=EN&vLastName=Brown

On workstations where this is not working the URL in the address bar appears as:

> G:\courses\flash\1\EN\course\html\certPopup.html

Browser is IE version **10.0.9200.16540** on all workstations.
Flash version is **WIN 11,6,602,180** or higher.

I'm really stumped as to why the URL in the address bar is different on different machines, with the parameters being stripped.

Answer (score 0):

The reason the first works and second doesn't is, that the first one is a URL, the second one is a file path. I have no idea if this might work, but try changing

```
var printURL = "html/certPopup.html";
```

to

```
var printURL = root.loaderInfo.loaderURL.replace(root.loaderInfo.loaderURL.split("/").pop(), ""); + "html/certPopup.html";
```

But since you are working on an offline project: Why don´t you work with AIR with captive runtime? Would be easier and the possibilities would be much greater?